# Codeigniter is too, too slow. What config is wrong?

Tags: codeigniter, profiler, mse

My web server was good with codeigniter, but after i  move my server on new windows server, it is too slow.
I checked my code step by step, but it is same config and code.
I just wrote simple code in main controller class.

```
public function testA()
{
  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
}
```

There is no mysql query, only show profiler data.

But it shows too slow.

Loading Time: Base Classes      8.4310

Controller Execution Time ( Batch / TestA )     7.7913

Total Execution Time    16.2224

The running time is 16 seconds.

What is wrong with codeigniter?

Comment: If it was fast on your other server it has to do with your server config. not with codeigniter.

Comment: What config do i have to checked? I don't clear why the code running is too slow.

Comment: Ìt's your server that is slow. We can't guess what your server config is. maybe it's something with your ram? we don't know.

Comment: ok. sorry. It is MSE (Microsoft Security Essential) problem. If i turn off real-time protection, then it rans in a 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is MSE (Microsoft Security Essential) problem. If i turn off real-time protection, then it rans in a 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I disabled Microsoft Security Essentials or Windows Defender real time protection and it solved the problem.

You can choose to exclude httpd.exe and or mysqld.exe from Windows Defender if you do not wish to disable real time protection.